# How to secure the Rest webservice by token based authentication?

Tags: java, security, authentication, spring-security, jax-rs

I have created few rest services using jersey implementation.
 In security concerns, service can invoke by any one. So  I decided to use the token based authentication system.
 I wrote one filter in spring security which handles every request before its hits the server.

One login service were created so user can invoke this service by passing the username and password for valid credentials it will generates the access token and expiry date and saves it in Hashmap and DB and returned as a response to the user.

For remaining services user have to pass the generated token in header to access the JAX-RS services.

All these process are coded by us i.e., generation,storage and expiration of the token.

Since we have some security API like oauth1,oauth2 in market  is it good to provide the security for rest service by above mentioned way???

Is oauth api will suits my requirement . If it is please guide me how to achieve this ?

Please help me out with valuable suggestions ???
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to implement same structure for my jersey web service which communicate to android iOS. can you please share some sample code for token generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've been in a similiar position before starting with our rest api. The only difference we had no exisitng code. So basically we saw 2 choices

1. Run our own Tokenhandling, that what you already have
2. Use something existing, i.e. oauth2

Our main requirement was authentification via token and we prefered an existing solution. So we just run with oauth2 in form of spring-security-oauth2, even we are not using the whole self authorization stuff.

- What i like and probably had missed in an own implementation is that a token generally identifies a user and a client combination and that clients can have rights too. Its nice to have this extra layer of security in our rest api, so i can block early on before even hitting one line of our code.
- In form of spring-security-oauth2 its proven code, which works and like much of spring its customizable. Example: In our first version we did use the provided JdbcTokenstore for storing the token, but as requirements changed, we just coded our own and switched it in the config.
- The disadvantage of using at least spring-security-oauth2 is that the whole authorization flow is normally webbased and needs communication between the client, the user and our app. As this would not work with our clients we had to trigger the token generation, etc ourselfs, which is doable with spring, but needed some code exploration :-)

If i had to build it again with java and where already using spring, i'd go with spring-security-oauth2 and the oauth way again. But when i had an existing working solution and dont need any of the oauth stuff i would keep the homegrown solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response azarai.
U have mentioned in your post that the security will provide to rest api using oauth or oauth2 .
But i have read that oauth suits when the third party server comes into picture correct me if am wrong ?
Here am not using any third party api like facebook,twiter etc..then how oauth suits for my requirement ?

Comment: A customers App is a third party server. OAuth help to "simplify" how server B (customer App) can talk with Server A (the Rest API) on behave of the user (which has accounts in both Apps/servers) and how to register and get access. After the user grants server B access rights to Server A, server A give an accessToken back. This token is used for the actual authentication when server B calls an api endpoint on server A.